# Notification timestamp & IsStarted from a ReplaySubject

Tags: .net, system.reactive

On Subscription, my ReplaySubject subcriber would like to know when the replay history has finished and it becomes a 'live' subscription. Furthermore, said subscriber would also like to receive the notification time for each item.

I figure the only way would be to copy the ReplaySubject source and make it return an object that contains Timestamped and a bool indicating the state of RemovableDisposable.IsStarted?

unless anyone can suggest a better alternative?

Comment: What have you got right now? It's kind of hard to guess at the exact setup from the information you've provided - you already have the `ReplaySubject`? How is it being "fed"? Does it currently timestamp events? Do you have the ability to change the declaration/behavior of it?

Comment: No, this is just a theoretical question of how it might be done. The timestamp i am refererring to is the ReplaySubjects own internal timestamp that wraps items as the are added to the subject.
I suppose a better way of phrasing this question might be, 'how do i expose the internal timestamps and subscription.isStarted of a replaysubject to a subscriber?' 
sorry for the confusion, thanks for listening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each item  which your replay subject provides, should be a wrapped item which includes a TimeStamp (indicating its original time when it was first created).
Do not confuse this with the Observable.TimeStamp() operator, which would give you an up to date (live) timestamp of each notification. Instead, you want to record the TimeStamp when the item was first played through the subject, and replay that same timestamp for any future subscribers.
i.e. If your observable is currently

```
IObservable<T>, you could change it to be IObservable<TimeStamped<T>>,
```

with your own custom Monad, the Rx 'Timestamped' one, (or just a simple wrapper class to start with if you wish).

Once you have this, I would have thought both requirements were pretty straightforward, but you wouldn't need a 'bool'.

Instead, your subscriber could cache their own TimeStamp, representing the time of subscription. You can then define:

- IsAReplayedItem = subscriberTimeStamp >= T.TimeStamp
- IsALiveItem = subscriberTimeStamp < T.TimeStamp

This keeps it simpler in my view.
The only way to have the subject be the one to tell you if it is replayed/live (rather than the client work it out by comparing TimeStamps), would be to write your own custom replay subject.
This would 'OnSubscribe', provide a new observer with its cached items, wrapped in a class with 'bool = true', followed by any future items in 'OnNext', with 'bool = false'. However, you would need to:
a) Cache previous items
b) Cache subscribers
c) Manage a fair amount of complexity surrounding handling an Update, whilst replaying your initial cache to a subscriber (effectively maintaining a cache, per subscriber).

This strikes me as being far more complicated with no real benefit. Keep it simple, and just use a timestamp.

Howard Andresier

p.s. The 'IsStarted' requirement can be solved by wrapping the ReplaySubject in a container class. This class can expose the underlying IObservable, but also maintain its own subscription which sets a local bool 'IsStarted' to true when it observes its first item.
Outside callers can then use the subject, or evaluate the 'IsStarted' bool at any time.

Comment: Thanks Howard, I didnt think of of using the timestamp in this way.

Comment: No worries. Just made a minor edit to point out that you can reuse the Timestamped<T> monad available within Rx, but not through the .TimeSTamp() extension method (just to wrap each of your values). Your subject will then be a IO<Timestamped<T>> from the outset - where the TimeStamp will be constant for each item, irrespective of when it is observed/replayed. i.e. Construct your own stream of these, and play them through your subject: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228977(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: Thanks, I already found Timestamped<T> before you mentioned, and indeed have used it to this effect. However, I am struggling a bit to see how each individual can subscriber know whether its own subscription has started or whether it is still receiving replay items, as this property is per subscriber. Is it possible to elaborate a little more on this point please?